# How to conditionally delete rows from data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
time<-c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
value<-c(1,1,6,1,2,6,2,2,1,1,6,1)

d<-data.frame(id, time, value)
```

The value 6 appears only once for each id. For every id, i would like to remove all rows with time greater than the time of the value 6

I would like the final data frame to have all observations for all ID's without "6". For those IDs having a "6" observation, i would like all observations with time < of that the time of the 6 observation.

I've searched SO, there are several questions (and answers) about conditional row deletion, but i found nothing close to what I need.

In the above case the final data frame should be

```
  id time value
1   1    0     1
2   1    1     1
3   1    2     6
5   2    0     2
6   2    1     6
9   3    0     1
10  3    1     1
11  3    2     6
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds off of Andrei's answer using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d, "id", function(x) subset(x, time <= x[x$value == 6, "time"]))
  id time value
1  1    0     1
2  1    1     1
3  1    2     6
4  2    0     2
5  2    1     6
6  3    0     1
7  3    1     1
8  3    2     6
```

**UPDATED TO ADDRESS COMMENTS IN NOTES**

Sample dataset to match description below:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
time<-c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,3,2,1)
value<-c(1,1,6,1,2,6,2,2,1,1,6,1,1,2,3)
d<-data.frame(id, time, value)
```

Add some additional checking in the anonymous function:

```
ddply(d, "id", 
      function(x) {
        if (any(x$value == 6)) {
          subset(x, time <= x[x$value == 6, "time"])
        } else {
          x
        }
      }
)
```

Check results

```
   id time value
1   1    0     1
2   1    1     1
3   1    2     6
4   2    0     2
5   2    1     6
6   3    0     1
7   3    1     1
8   3    2     6
9   4    3     1
10  4    2     2
11  4    1     3
```

Comment: This however removes also all "Id"'s that do not have a 6 value. Is it possible to modify so that id's without "6" are also included in the final dataset?

Comment: @ECII - if there's an ID w/o a value == 6, what do you want to do with those records? Return all of them? Return none of them?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry that I was unclear. I would like the final data frame to have all observations for all ID's without "6". For those IDs having a "6" observation, i would like all observations with time < of that the time of the 6 observation.

Comment: @ECII - it feels hacky, but check my updated answer, should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Select time at value 6 for each id:

```
mt <- d[d$value == 6, c("id","time")]
names(mt) <- c("id", "max.time")
```

Merge d and mt to have maximum time per id:

```
d <- merge(d,mt)
```

Subset and clean up:

```
d <- subset(d, time <= max.time)
d$max.time <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your selection method for 6.  If that is user defined then the following will give you the selected rows:

```
x <- max(d[d$value==6, 'time']) #find the max time associate with value =6
subset(d, time<=x)   #subset and select only time less than or = to 6
```

If you are looking to automate the value of 6 and are looking for the largest value share by all ID's exactly one time here is the convoluted way I did it.  Anytime you see unlist that often I know sapply would be a betetr choice and probably a whole other approach but without know for certain how 6 is selected this is what I put forth now:

```
y <- with(d, by(value, id, FUN=rle))
z <- lapply(seq_along(y), function(x) unlist(y[[x]][1])==1)
j <- lapply(seq_along(y), function(x) unlist(y[[x]][2])[z[[x]]])
mv <- max(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(subset(data.frame(table(unlist(j))), 
    Freq==length(j))['Var1']))))

x <- max(d[d$value==mv, 'time'])
subset(d, time<=x)
```