# Deleting Rows per ID when value gets greater than... minus 2

Tags: r, row

I have the following data frame

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
time<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
value<-c(1,1,6,1,2,0,0,1,2,6,2,2,1,1,6,1)

d<-data.frame(id, time, value)
```

The value 6 appears only once for each id. For every id, i would like to remove all rows after the line with the value 6 per id except the first two lines coming after.

I've searched and found a similar problem, but i couldnt adapt it myself. I therefore use the [code of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501082/how-to-conditionally-delete-rows-from-data-frame)

In the above case the final data frame should be

```
id  time value
1    0     1
1    1     1
1    2     6
1    3     1
1    4     2
2    0     2
2    1     6
2    2     2
2    3     2
3    0     1
3    1     1
3    2     6
3    3     1
```

On of the solution given seems getting very close to what i need. But i didn't manage to adapt it. Could u help me?

```
library(plyr)

ddply(d, "id", 
      function(x) {
        if (any(x$value == 6)) {
          subset(x, time <= x[x$value == 6, "time"])
        } else {
          x
        }
      }
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: So what is the desired out put here? You have only one id which seem to satisfy this condition. Are you looking for something  like `library(data.table) ; setDT(d)[, .SD[1:(which(value == 6L) + 2L)], by = id]`?

Comment: Well in this example of course... but my real dataset is alot bigger...

Comment: When i try it with my data it says "Error in 1:(which(value == 6L) + 2L) : argument of length 0"

Comment: You don't have 6 in that certain group then, while you clearly stated that you always do. How do you want to handle such situations? Anyway, see akruns answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`).  Grouped by the 'id' column, we get the position of 'value' that is equal to 6.  Add 2 to it.  Find the `min` of the number of elements for that group (.N) and the position, get the `seq`, and use that to subset the dataset.  We can also add an `if/else` condition to check whether there are `any` 6 in the 'value' column or `else` to return `.SD` without any subsetting.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, if(any(value==6)) .SD[seq(min(c(which(value==6) + 2, .N)))] 
                  else .SD, by = id]
#     id time value
# 1:  1    0     1
# 2:  1    1     1
# 3:  1    2     6
# 4:  1    3     1
# 5:  1    4     2
# 6:  2    0     2
# 7:  2    1     6
# 8:  2    2     2
# 9:  2    3     2
#10:  3    0     1
#11:  3    1     1
#12:  3    2     6
#13:  3    3     1
#14:  4    0     1
#15:  4    1     2
#16:  4    2     5
```

Or as @Arun mentioned in the comments, we can use the `?head` to subset, which would be faster

```
setDT(d)[, if(any(value==6)) head(.SD, which(value==6L)+2L) else .SD, by = id]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'id', get the position of 'value' 6 with `which`, add 2, get the `seq` and use that numeric index within `slice` to extract the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(seq(which(value==6)+2))
#   id time value
#1   1    0     1
#2   1    1     1
#3   1    2     6
#4   1    3     1
#5   1    4     2
#6   2    0     2
#7   2    1     6
#8   2    2     2
#9   2    3     2
#10  3    0     1
#11  3    1     1
#12  3    2     6
#13  3    3     1
#14  4    0     1
#15  4    1     2
#16  4    2     5
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L), value = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L)), .Names = c("id", 
"time", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: is it just me or is it just me or `data.table` filtering is eye-hurting?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was trying to make it more clear.

Comment: This one works till the first time of value=6 and then stops... So i think the "by = id" would need to fit somewhere there?

Comment: 1. There is only one 6 per id and 2. sorry i forgot about that. If there is no 6 in an id, none of the rows should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and I think u guys are awesome.

Comment: @user3389108 Can you also try with the `dplyr` solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I thought `slice` would show some errors, but it seems to work

Comment: Or `setDT(d)[, head(.SD, which(value==6L)+2L), by=id]`

Comment: @akrun dplyr is better sometimes

Comment: @ExperimenteR yes, the dplyr code looks more compact